# Is there a sequence in which after a certain point the terms seem to stay inside some epsilon neighborhood and then suddenly they do not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does there exist a sequence that settles down for awhile and then blows up to large values? My intuition originally said no, but then I was thinking about things like $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty, a_n = 2^{-1000+n}$.

This question is about understanding the weakness of intuition when it comes to convergence of sequence, thus necessitating rigor.

But above wasn't really what I wanted, so I am still unsure. More specifically is there a sequence that **appears to converge**, and then blows up. I was thinking about this when reading the topological version of convergence: There exists a point in the sequence after which all terms are in some epsilon neighborhood, is there ever a sequence in which after a certain point the terms seem to stay inside some epsilon neighborhood and then suddenly they do not?

Sequence not defined by a piecewise function please, i.e not broken up into a bunch of functions defined on subdomains.

Comment: What about $$a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{c l}0, & n<10^{10^{10}}\\ n, & n\geq 10^{10^{10}}\end{array}\right.$$.

Comment: @detnvvp oh I didn't consider piece-wise defined, I guess I don't really want that

Comment: For a sequence to "seem to" do anything is not a well-defined mathematical concept.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes, but I don't know how to formalise my question, so it's unavoidable

Comment: For that matter, neither is "piece-wise defined".

Comment: @fkraiem Well that is simply not true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise

Comment: If you want something using fomula, $a_n = \prod_{k=1}^P (n-k)$ satisfies $a_1 = \cdots a_P = 0$ and then goes to infiinity.

Comment: The sequence $a_n = 2^{-n}+2^{n-1000}$ appears to tend to zero if you only look at $n \le 500$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @FunctionalAnalysis *Piecewise is actually a way of expressing the function, rather than a characteristic of the function itself.*

Comment: @fkraiem Yes my sequence is defined by a function, and I don't want the sequence defined by a piece wise function

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oh yes, that's good, that's what I wanted, thanks, I was so close :D

Comment: $a_n = \exp (n/10^{10,000})$ pretty much looks like $1,1,1,\dots $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

For any large integer $M$, the sequence $a_n = 2^{-n}+2^{n-2M}$ is decreasing for $0 \le n \le M$, and in some non-rigorous sense, "appears" to tend to $0$ if you only look at the first $M$ terms. However, the sequence diverges.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to see what you expect. Maybe you want to prescribe that  $a_n $ is given by some (nice) formula?

Otherwise, let  $m $ be your favorite big number and let 
$$a_n=\begin {cases}1,&\ n\leq m\\ n,&\ n>m\end {cases}
$$